# Add user to RDS instance - MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm not used to AWS and how some services actually work but in this exact moment I need to add some users to a MySQL database (RDS service) and allow some IPs to access it, and if someone can help me I really appreciate.

I did some research and found that I can connect to the EC2 instance and access the CLI and that would be enough, but I can't find any running instance in any region.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The way I handled configuring MySQL in AWS was to install the MySQL CLI on the EC2 node which I intended to use the database.  Then, all I needed to do was to SSH into that EC2 node, and configure the MySQL instance as I would any MySQL instance.  Regarding whitelisting IP addresses, this can easily be done from the AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to your RDS instance as the root user, and add an account just like you would with a MySQL database running anywhere else. There is no special AWS procedure here.
2. If the database has the "publicly accessible" flag enabled, then you just need to add the IP address to the inbound rules in the Security Group assigned to the RDS instance. If the database is not "publicly accessible" then you won't be able to give access to external IP addresses.